# Confusion in results of descendant-or-self-node in xpath i.e. // within the xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Consider following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="Animal" align="center">
            <h2>Animal</h2>
            <div class="Vertebrate" align="left" >
                <h3 align="left">Vertebrate</h3>
                <div class="Fish">
                    <h4 >Fish</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="Mammal">
                    <h4>Mammal</h4>
                    <div class="Herbivore">
                        <h5>Herbivore</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Carnivore">
                        <h5>Carnivore</h5>
                        <div class="Lion">
                            <h6>Lion</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="Tiger">
                            <h6>Tiger</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Other">
                    <h4>Other</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Invertebrate">
                <h3>Invertebrate</h3>
                <div class="Insect">
                    <h4>Insect</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="Crustacean">
                    <h4>Crustacean</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I gave xpath as:

```
//div[@class='Mammal']//preceding::div
```

Note the // after first div element in above xpath. It is for descendant-or-self-node.

It gave results as:

```
<div class="Fish">
<div class="Herbivore">
<div class="Carnivore">
<div class="Lion">
<div class="Tiger">
```

I want to ask why it is including `<div class="Carnivore">` and `<div class="Tiger">` in results?

To whom `<div class="Carnivore">` is preceding?

And regarding `<div class="Tiger">` it is the parent of `<h6>Tiger</h6>` how it is preceding it? Parent should not be incuded in preceding axes in xpath.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question, you can not expect us to go through a link fully and understand what was the issue and how it got resolved ?

Comment: the answer is because you are using // after this `//div[@class='Mammal']`, basically A double slash "//" means any descendant node of the current node in the HTML tree which matches the locator.

Comment: @cruisepandey I am using `//div[@class='Mammal']//preceding::div` which says preceding of div[@class='Mammal'] or any descendant if it. But to whom `<div class="Carnivore">` and `<div class="Tiger">` is preceding?

Comment: I guess you meant `//div[@class='Mammal']//*/preceding::div` (or `//div[@class='Mammal']/descendant-or-self::*/preceding::div`)?

Comment: @Joe I meant `//div[@class='Mammal']//preceding::div` which in other terms means `//div[@class='Mammal']/descendant-or-self/preceding::div`. There is no * in between.